# Sharepoint 2013 configuration failed - SPException

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I'm trying to configure Sharepoint 2013 and I'm receiving the following error in the configurator:

> An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException was thrown.  Additional exception information: There is no file with URL '_catalogs/masterpage/minimal.master' in this Web.

What could be the cause? How to deal with this?

In the IIS manager I don't see the web application for Sharepoint. Shouldn't it be created by the installer?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by configurator?

Comment: How do you install Sharepoint? I would recommend to use AutoSPInstaller it will ensure that the farm is provisioned and best practices are applied. https://autospinstaller.com/